# Designing two programs to accomplish a text-processing task on Windows

Tags: windows, algorithm, text-processing

**Task:** Given the song lyrics of a sufficiently large and skew-free sampling of every American and U.K. song, take the lyrics, decompose them into unique words (called lyrics'), and then store them into a growing list of unique words (called the lexicon). If lyrics' has words not stored in the lexicon, then those words are added to the lexicon. If every word in lyrics' is also found in the lexicon, then adding lyrics' causes the lexicon to remain the same (idempotency).

**Objects:** One program to turn the song lyrics into a list of unique words, one program to add the output of the first program to the lexicon, and the lexicon itself (probably a simple .txt file, but if there's something better, please recommend.)

**Operating System:** Windows 11 Home.

The concern is that the list might grow very large, so large, that doing a linear search through the lexicon of each word in lyrics' to check for uniqueness might be prohibitively expensive.

What would be the most efficient way to set up and program these three objects so that this task might be *successful*?

Comment: AFAIK there are about 170,000 unique words in English.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Part of the intention of this project is to identify the subset of those 170,000 words (which by the way is *very small* for a human language: Latin had 10 million unique words and that was when people literally wrote on ceramic pots and sheepskin aka vellum) that are simple English. And the criterion is: simple English are the words people would use in a rock or pop song.

Comment: I'm just suggesting that so few words can be stored fairly easily.